# How to use sympy.Poly on scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline?

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

```py
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
from sympy import Symbol, Poly

xpts = np.linspace(0, 1)
cs = CubicSpline(xpts, np.exp(xpts))
Poly(cs)
```

How to get the polynomial expression of scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline using sympy.Poly?

Answer (score 2):

The cubic spline is made of many different polynomials. You can get their coefficients with the `.c` attribute:

```
In [33]: cs.c.shape
Out[33]: (4, 49)
```

This is an array of 4 rows and 49 columns. Each column gives the coefficients of one polynomial:

```
In [35]: cs.c[:,0]
Out[35]: array([0.17111101, 0.49985044, 1.00000156, 1.        ])
```

This represents a polynomial and can be converted to a SymPy polynomial as:

```
In [41]: x = Symbol('x')

In [42]: Poly(cs.c[:,0], x)
Out[42]: Poly(0.171111008723916*x**3 + 0.499850444583089*x**2 + 1.00000155672475*x + 1.0, x, domain='RR')
```

This plot shows that this polynomial closely follows the exponential curve near to x=0:

```
In [40]: plot(Poly(cs.c[:,0], x).as_expr(), exp(x))
```

That's the first polynomial but there are 48 others which you can get using an index other than `0`. The coefficients are the coefficients for a polynomial centred at the origin so shifting is needed to get the right coefficients:

```
In [46]: plot(Poly(cs.c[:,48], x).as_expr().subs(x, x-xpts[-1]), exp(x))
```